# How can I ignore a file that has previously been processed in ADF

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory, pipeline

How can I ignore a file in sharepoint that has previously been processed? The ADF pipeline shouldn't process the file without moving it to another archive folder until a new file is uploaded in the folder.

Expectation should be the file should not move to other folder but the file should not picked for the processing, If an new files uploaded then it should be picked by for the processing

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach to achieve your requirement.

**NOTE**: For this method, if you are copying the files for the first time from the source location, you need to copy the entire files for the first pipeline run and then modify the pipeline like below first next scheduling of pipeline.

First, create the [**`SharePointOnlineListResource`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list-copy-activity#prerequisites) dataset to list out the files in the site. Specify your list name or Documents if your files are in the Documents.

[image]

Now, use lookup query to filter out the files like below.

```
$select=Name,Created,Path,&$filter=ContentType eq 'Document'
```

[image]

This will list out all the files with Creation date of it.

[image]

Now, use Filter activity, to filter out the latest files(files created after the last pipeline run).

Here, My file creation dates are in `UTC-7` format so converted them to `UTC` by adding 7 hours. You need to do it as per your file dates.

Also, I am filtering out the files which are created in the last 60 minutes (from last pipeline run). You need to give this value as per your pipeline scheduling difference.

**Items**: `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

**Condition**:

```
@lessOrEquals(div(sub(ticks(utcnow()),ticks(addToTime(item().Created,7,'Hour'))),600000000),60)
```

[image]

You can see the latest files list.

[image]

Pass this array `@activity('Filter1').output.Value` to a ForEach activity and iterate through these list. Inside ForEach, use the copy activity and pass the **file path from the above array** in each iteration to the source of copy activity by using dataset parameters.

Comment: I have one pipeline, which run daily. Monthly once i will get files in the folder once processed it should not pick the same fail to process again

Comment: In the condition I have given trigger intervel of 60 minutes, you need to give trigger intervel of 1 day(in minutes) in that condition. Then it will filter the newly created files within the last 1 day(which are not processed by previous pipeline run).

Comment: Thanks for the response, the created timestamp I'm not getting from the source file

Comment: You should get it, are you using lookup activity and query right? Can you provide the output of lookup picture.